# Java Repeatable annotation not recognized when it's only one parameter

Tags: java, annotations

I want to create an option class that holds a key-value structure.

This Map is filled with the content of a configuration file at runtime.

To validate that Config I want do define required keys per annotation of the Option class like:

```
// Map must contain a entry with key 'foo' and key 'bar'
@requiredKey("foo")
@requiredKey("bar")
class Options {
   Map<String, String> optionsMap;
}
```

Therefore I created a repeatable annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface requiredKeys {
    requireKey[] value();
}

@Repeatable(requiredKeys)
public @interface requredKey {
    String value();
}
```

At runtime I call `requiredKey[] anno = options.getAnnotationsByType(requiredKey.class))`

This works fine if the number of specified annotations is > 1. But if the number of annotations is exactly one, I cant obtain it (`getAnnotationsByType` returns an empty array)

working:

```
@requiredKey("foo")
@requiredKey("bar")
class Options {
   Map<String, String> optionsMap;
}

// anno holds 'foo' and 'bar'
requiredKey[] anno = options.getAnnotationsByType(requiredKey.class))
```

not working:

```
@requiredKey("foo")
class Options {
   Map<String, String> optionsMap;
}

// anno is empty
requiredKey[] anno = options.getAnnotationsByType(requiredKey.class))
```

I don't understand this behaviour :(

So my Questions are:

- what's the explanation for such an behaviour?
- how can I get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add to your `@requiredKey` the retention policy:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Repeatable(requiredKeys)
public @interface requredKey {
    String value();
}
```

If you don't, then when you create a class with one annotation, Java does not create a `requiredKeys` annotation because you have only one `Annotation`. Therefor, the retention policy of the `@requiredKey` is applied. In your case, you had none, which means that your annotation won't be visible by the JVM.

Other comments: Please use Capital letter for your class/annotations.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RequiredKeys {
    requireKey[] value();
}

@Repeatable(RequiredKeys)
public @interface RequiredKey {
    String value();
}
```